# Adapting "module" alias (invoking modulecmd) from tcsh to bash

Tags: linux, bash, tcsh, environment-modules

In tcsh, I can run commands like:

```
 module add jdk/1.8.0_162
```

...using an alias defined as such:

```
alias module 'eval `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd tcsh \!*`'
```

I'm trying to get an equivalent to this for bash.

---

Currently, I've tried making a separate bash function for each subcommand, like so:

```
function module_add {
    /app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd bash add $1 2>>err.log
}

function module_rm {
    /app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd bash rm $1 2>>err.log
}

function module_list {
    /app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd bash list
}

java -version
module_list
module_rm 'j2re'
module_add 'jdk/1.8.0_162'
module_add 'gtk+/2.24.17'
module_list
java -version
```

I can be sure the program calls have been executed, since the unexisting module (added by purpose for testing) gtk+/2.24.17 creates an entry in err.log.

However, java -version still shows the same older version and module_list does not show any new modules. Everything works great in tcsh (where I use the module add alias instead). I have tried different versions of module command. The latest version tested is 3.2.10. The result is the same on RHEL6 and RHEL7

Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT**

Based on some clever comments I tried to the exact same command for tcsh

```
/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd tcsh add jdk/1.8.0_162
```

and it gave the same result. Anyone who knows the difference between that command and

```
module add jdk/1.8.0_162
```

in tcsh?

So I guess the question is rather about how the modulescmd differ from the tcsh alias `module add`

BR
Patrik

Comment: I don't see how any of the problems you are seeing relate to `bash`. The only shell problem would be the failure to quote`$1`, but given the arguments you are passing to `module_add`, that isn't the source of your problem.

Comment: @chepner You have a point, i just noticed that the exact same command works the same way for tcsh. Any idea why `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd tcsh add jdk/1.8.0_162` and `module add jdk/1.8.0_162` works differently in tcsh?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would say this is about the tsch alias `module add`. I add the tag tcsh, since this now seems to be a question about how tcsh works.

Comment: It looks to me like the alias just runs modulecmd, and modulecmd is responsible for doing the work. Or, rather, emitting a script on output that does the work.

Comment: When you run the bash version, does it emit something that looks like shell commands on stdout?

Comment: ...anyhow, if you show a working tcsh implementation of the aliases you want (instead of just asserting that there *is* a tcsh alias, show it!), I'd be more able to provide bash alternatives (assuming that modulecmd's generation of equivalent bash scripts as output does in fact work correctly).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes it does. It output something that looks as if it is setting some environment variables. Btw, got it now, Looks quite obvious when I look at it now... alias module
eval `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd tcsh !*`

Comment: Good -- that's what I assumed it was in writing my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`modulecmd`](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/module.html) emits shell scripts on its stdout (thus the argument telling it which shell to generate a script for).

A shell needs to actually execute those commands for them to take effect; this is what `eval` does. (Don't ever use `eval` unless you trust the people who wrote the program that generated the output you're `eval`ing to be rigorous about corner cases -- it [lends itself to security bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Thus, if your existing tcsh alias for the `module` command is:

```
alias module 'eval `/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd tcsh \!*`'
```

...the bash equivalent would be:

```
module() { eval "$(/app/modules/0/bin/modulecmd bash "$@")"; }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks and great job.